# Passing multiple JSON ("rows" or object) to a Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

```
var POS = {
        AddItem: function (SKU) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: '{"code":"itm-0008", "qty":"5"},
                       {"code":"itm-0009", "qty":"1"},
                       {"code":"l1", "qty":"8"}',
                url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct", "POS")',
                success: function (data) {
                   alert("Items Successfully Added!");
                },
                error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                    alert(errorObj.toString());
                }
            });
        }
};
```

This is my Controller: (It can only handle one(1) JSON "row" or object)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddProduct(Item items)
    {
        Inventory inv = new Inventory();

        inv.Add(items.code, items.qty);
        inv.Dispose();
    }
```

How can i pass this multiple JSON "row" or object to a Controller?

Comment: `var POS = {
        AddItem: function (SKU) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: '[{code:"itm-0008", qty:"5"},
                       {code:"itm-0009", qty:"1"},
                       {code:"l1", qty:"8"}]',
                url: '@Url.Action("AddProduct", "POS")',
                success: function (data) {
                   alert("Items Successfully Added!");
                },
                error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                    alert(errorObj.toString());
                }
            });
        }
};`

Comment: `[HttpPost]
    public void AddProduct(List<Item> items)
    {
        Inventory inv = new Inventory();
        foreach (var _items in items)
        {
                inv.Add(_items.code, _items.qty);
        }
        
        inv.Dispose();
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your json to an array of object:

```
[{"code":"itm-0008", "qty":"5"},
                   {"code":"itm-0009", "qty":"1"},
                   {"code":"l1", "qty":"8"}']
```

Controller:

```
for each(var item in items)
      inv.Add(item.code, item.qty);
```

Comment: And pass `List<Item>` to the controller action

Comment: `data:[{"code":"itm-0008", "qty":"5"},
                       {"code":"itm-0009", "qty":"1"},
                       {"code":"l1", "qty":"8"}],`
I tested it.. but it passes null values. Can you please tell my mistake?

Comment: the parameters in the Controller..
and also i Added this:
`datatype: "json",` in the script..

Comment: Well the view needs to post a list

Comment: So please change your model to use `List<Item>`

Comment: Thanks its working now.. i just made this changes:
`'[{code:"itm-0008", qty:"5"}, {code:"itm-0009", qty:"1"}, {code:"l1", qty:"8"}]'`